# Open Source Portal Container other than Gatein

Tags: open-source, portal, gatein

We have done a proof-of-concept using Gatein 3.5 which runs well with JBoss AS7.

However, JBoss AS7 only has a community edition and we cannot proceed with it. Thus, we have to switch to JBoss 6 enterprise version.

Unfortunately, Gatein doesn't work with JBoss 6. I had raised this issue in JBoss/Gatein community and they stated that [Gatein in JBoss 6 is not a good combination](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/217552?tstart=0&_sscc=t).

Please let me know some open source portal container which can run on JBoss 6.

Answer (score 1):

Bipul, I think you misunderstood the recommendation in the forum.

You were proposed to upgrade from 3.4 (With JBoss AS 6) to 3.5 With JBoss AS 7.

If you are looking for a solution with GateIn 3.5 and JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6, you should know that we will very soon release JBoss Portal Platform 6 that will be exactly this.

You can already download an evaluation version here:
https://access.redhat.com/downloads#eval

Tomorrow (Tuesday), there is an intro to the platform: https://engage.redhat.com/forms/20130212_JBossPP_tipsandtricks?sc_cid=70160000000URk2AAG&offer_id=701600000007O1kAAE

Thomas